# Accessing System Keychain using Swift

Tags: swift, keychain, macos-sierra

I need to access the System keychain on MacOS to update the ACL on certain elements. I already fail when I try to access the keychain though.

I do have sample code where I can access and work with the login (default) keychain mainly due to the following nil:

```
SecItemAdd(keychainQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
```

What do I need to provide when accessing a different keychain? I can't find any way to create a *SecKeychain* object.

How do I need to complete the initialisation to be able to create an item into the system keychain as a start?